# What is the most efficient way to search for an optimal building to launch a rocket from?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, optimization, big-o

I'm currently working on algorithms with the intention of improving my skills. Right now I'm stuck with a problem that I cannot let go of my mind.
It goes like this:

> I receive 100 sets of configurations that each contain an array of
>   numbers which resemble the height of a sky scraper. Now I need to find
>   a sky scraper in this array which allows the best view to launch a
>   rocket from.
>   The conditions are that all subsequent buildings must be
>   higher (can't be of equal height) than the one it started from, the first
>   building's height after the sky scraper that the rocket is launched
>   from is irrelevant. What is relevant is the height of the following
>   buildings.

For example:

```
Input: 5 4 3 4 5
```

The best sky scraper to launch from is 3 because there are totally 4 sky scrapers that have a view onto this sky scraper.

Output would be 4

I have a implementation that is O(n^2) but is too slow to handle 1000s of sky scrapers...

```
# read all configurations
while configs > 0:
    count = int(input())
    h = list(map(int, str(input()).split()))

    if buildings_count > 1:
        if allValuesAreSame(h):
            results.append(2 if count > 2 else 1)
        else:
            places = [0 for x in range(buildings_count)]

            for sample_index in range(count):
                last_high = -1
                for i in range(count):
                    if i == sample_index:
                        last_high = -1
                    else:
                        if i < sample_index:
                            if last_high == -1:
                                last_high = h[i]
                                places[sample_index] += 1
                            else:
                                if h[i] < last_high:
                                    last_high = h[i]
                                    places[sample_index] += 1
                        elif i > sample_index:
                            if last_high == -1:
                                last_high = h[i]
                                places[sample_index] += 1
                            else:
                                if h[i] > last_high:
                                    last_high = h[i]
                                    places[sample_index] += 1

        results.append(max(places))
    else:
        results.append(0)

    print(f'{results[-1]}')
    configs -= 1
```

Does anybody know how to optimize this algorithm? I've been working for days now on this and don't know how to optimize it further..

Comment: Please provide a complete, precise, and accurate specification of your requirements.

Comment: _Does anybody know how to optimize this algorithm_ This implies that you're not interested in a better (but completely different) algorithm...

Comment: the input contains a list of numbers that are the heights of the skycrapers..

then the algorithm should find the optimal place to launch a rocket from, it should output the most amount of sky scrapers that have a view onto a sky scraper from which a rocket is launched

Answer (score 0):

Count the sequence of decreasing buildings that lead up until a given building, then count the sequence of increasing. Store the sum of the decreasing streak plus the increasing streak. This should allow O(n)

Roughly in pseudo-code:

```
decreasing = 0
increasing = 0
best = 0

for building in buildings:

    if building< last_building:
        decreasing +=1
    else
        past_decreasing = decreasing
        decreasing =0 

    if building > last_building:
        increasing +=1
    else:
        past_increasing = increasing
        increasing =0 

    if past_increasing+past_decreasing >best
         best = past_increasing+past_decreasing
```

This or some variation of the idea should allow you to loop only once.

Comment: I already do that, the problem is that I'm searching for the best sky scraper to launch a rocket from, so I need to go through each building to have as a start and then do your algorithm which is O(n^2)

Comment: Not really, because at each time you check a building you are carrying the count of previous higher buildings and either increasing this count or counting the posterior higher buildings, so the building on the iteration loop is only being counted, it is not a candidate. The ideia (if my understanding of the question is correct) is that a valid sequence of buildings containing a good spot for launch has a strictly decreasing sequence of buildings, the launch building then the strictly increasing sequence.

Comment: If after an increase, the height of the next building decreases, you know you have broken the sequence, you rank the candidate you had found and then you start counting the for next sequence.

Comment: the idea is that I need to find a building x with height h that has the most sky scraper that can view x under the condition that all scrapers left from x are lower than the next one (towards x) and that all scrapers right from x are higher than the next one (away from x)

Comment: so that

5 4 3 1 6 8 9

1 in that case has the best spot since there are 3 buildings left from it, that can view 1 and 3 buildings right from it that can view 1 (under the conditions previously mentioned)

so the most amount of sky scrapers c that can watch a sky scraper in this sequence is 6